# Multiple inheritance in solidity, identifier not found or not unique, what's going on?

Tags: inheritance, import, solidity

I am attempting to get [random numbers](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf) and also use a [chainlink alarm](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-alarm-clock) in the same contract. To do this, I want to use solidity's multiple inheritance feature. Using the following splice of my code:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
//import "github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, ChainlinkClient {
```

Testing this in [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), I am getting the following error:

```
browser/lottery4.sol:6:38: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, ChainlinkClient {
^-------------^
```

I have tried mixing the imports, and inheritance order, to no luck. I can only assume it has something to do with the imports.

When I un-comment the second import, ie:

```
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
```

I get the following error, which I only assume is due to inheritance.

```
browser/lottery4.sol:4:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
import "github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol:3:1: The previous declaration is here:
interface LinkTokenInterface {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

What am I missing?